# How to know the source of firing the trigger

Tags: trigger

I have a requirement where one object(Class__c) firing trigger of before update of Plan_Product__c.Now i want to check if firing is due to class__c or due to plan_product__c.Actually i want to allow updating of some fields of plan_product__c if firing is due to class__c,otherwise don't want to allow.
How can we achived this in salesforce...Sequence is class causes planproducts to udpate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use static variable. In your Util (or other class of the same usage) class, define:

```
static Boolean inPlanProductTrigger = false;
```

In your Plan_Product__c trigger, update the value to be true.

```
Util.inPlanProductTrigger = true;
```

Then you can tell in your class__c trigger, whether it is fired by Plan_Prodcut__c trigger or not.

Comment: Thanks Lance for quick reply..My Requirement is, value of PlanProducts's premium__c will only get updated if it source is from Class__C Trigger. Write now we have trigger on both planproduct and class..Existing functionality causes class to fire planproduct trigger.Now i want premium only get update if planproduct trigger got fired due to class,not due to anyother cause.

Comment: @ArunSharma I don't see a reason you can't use static variable to resolve the issue in your scenario

Comment: Thanks Lance,That was perfect shot..Thanks once again It worked